# Measuring weighted mean length from an electrophoresis gel image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

#### Background:

My question relates to extracting feature from an electrophoresis gel (see below). In this gel, DNA is loaded from the top and allowed to migrate under a voltage gradient. The gel has sieves so smaller molecules migrate further than longer molecules resulting in the separation of DNA by length. So higher up the molecule, the longer it is.

#### Question:

In this image there are 9 lanes each with separate source of DNA. I am interested in measuring the mean location (value on the y axis) of each lane.
I am really new to image processing, but I do know MATLAB and I can get by with R with some difficulty. I would really appreciate it if someone can show me how to go about finding the mean of each lane.

[image: gel_image]

Comment: Can you post a larger image?  Also, how automated does this need to be?

Comment: I have edited your question. Were you interested in MATLAB commands specifically or just a general image processing approach (i.e., language independent)? If the former, you can leave your question here. But if it's the latter, I'd suggest [dsp.se]. That site's better if you're looking to learn and understand how this is done. However, please **do not** post your question there too. If you want to move it, you can flag for attention or let me know and I'll do it.

Comment: reve_etrange and yoda many thanks for your response.@reve_etrange: It need not be automated at all--it can be interactive (I only have couple of gels). I will immediately upload a larger image. yoda: Matlab would be the easiest (I have image processing toolbox) because I know how to use it better than R or any other language. If you feel Signal Processing is better, please post it for me. Many thanks

Comment: I've uploaded the larger image to http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/588/gele.png

Comment: @LeeSande: Will all of your gels be this pretty?

Comment: @Jonas Thankyou for your response. Yes, the gels would be this clean

Comment: Maybe better on dsp.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my try. It requires that the gels are nice (i.e. straight lanes and the gel should not be rotated), but should otherwise work fairly generically. Note that there are two image-size-dependent parameters that will need to be adjusted to make this work on images of different size.

```
%# first size-dependent parameter: should be about 1/4th-1/5th
%# of the lane width in pixels.
minFilterWidth = 10;

%# second size-dependent parameter for filtering the 
%# lane profiles
gaussWidth = 5;

%# read the image, normalize to 0...1
img = imread('http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/588/gele.png');
img = rgb2gray(img);
img = double(img)/255;

%# Otsu thresholding to (roughly) find lanes
thMsk = img < graythresh(img);
```

[image]

```
%# count the mask-pixels in each columns. Due to 
%# lane separation, there will be fewer pixels
%# between lanes
cts = sum(thMsk,1);
```

[image]

```
%# widen the local minima, so that we get a nice
%# separation between lanes
ctsEroded = imerode(cts,ones(1,minFilterWidth));

%# use imregionalmin to identify the separation 
%# between lanes. Invert to get a positive mask
laneMsk = ~repmat(imregionalmin(ctsEroded),size(img,1),1);
```

Image with lanes that will be used for analysis

[image]

```
%# for each lane, create an averaged profile
lblMsk = bwlabel(laneMsk);
nLanes = max(lblMsk(:));

profiles = zeros(size(img,1),nLanes);
midLane = zeros(1,nLanes);

for i = 1:nLanes
profiles(:,i) = mean(img.*(lblMsk==i),2);
midLane(:,i) = mean(find(lblMsk(1,:)==i));
end

%# Gauss-filter the profiles (each column is an
%# averaged intensity profile
G = exp(-(-gaussWidth*5:gaussWidth*5).^2/(2*gaussWidth^2));
G=G./sum(G);
profiles = imfilter(profiles,G','replicate'); %'
```

[image]

```
%# find the minima
[~,idx] = min(profiles,[],1);

%# plot
figure,imshow(img,[])
hold on, plot(midLane,idx,'.r')
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for the link to ImageJ. I actually did use ImageJ but the link you point to measures the area under the intensity. However, it does not give the y-axis location of the peak. I am actually interested in finding out the location of the peak for each lane. Actually, one complication is that there might be saturation and so one would not have a nice peak but flat region on the top. I wonder how one can go about finding the middle of that.

Comment: @LeeSande: I have added a way to automatically extract the profile and identify the peak.

Comment: Sorry for the delay--I just logged in today. Your answer looks very comprehensive and very helpful. Many thanks!

Comment: @LeeSande: Thanks. A few suggestions: (1) you may want to plot the negative profiles for better visualization. (2) You can easily use this code to calculate the weighted mean instead of the peak of the bars; I suggest to clip the profiles at the median of the masked region, though.

Comment: I just tried your code and it works perfectly. Your comments are great and very helpful. Can you please tell me how I can compute the weighted mean? Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas: This is a *very* satisfying answer.

Comment: @LeeSande: I might not have the time this week since I'm preparing for a big conference next week. Please remind me again, either via this site or by email (see profile link) in about two weeks.

Comment: @Jonas Hi Jonas, just a reminder for your help with how to compute the weighted mean (instead of just the mean). Thanks

Comment: @Jonas
i tried ur code but it doesn't work with me also
thier is no error also no answer how can i solve that??

Answer (score 4):

Here's my stab at a simple template for an interactive way to do this:

```
% Load image
img = imread('gel.png');
img = rgb2gray(img);

% Identify lanes
imshow(img)
[x,y] = ginput;

% Invert image
img = max(img(:)) - img;

% Subtract background
[xn,yn] = ginput(1);
noise   = img((yn-2):(yn+2), (xn-2):(xn+2));
noise   = mean(noise(:));
img     = img - noise;

% Calculate means
means = (1:size(img,1)) * double(img(:,round(x))) ./ sum(double(img(:,round(x))), 1);

% Plot
hold on
plot(x, means, 'r.')
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! I tried your code but I am stuck at the ginput stage--I am suppose to select the lane (one by one?) but I am not sure how to tell the program that I have selected the lane (cross-hairs still stay). Many thanks

Comment: @LeeSande Sorry that is my fault, I should have said. You click once for each lane and then hit enter when you are done selecting lanes. The cross hair will pop back up one more time for you to select a region of background intensity (I selected somewhere in the bottom left).

Comment: Thanks again. I now click once (any where on the lane?) at one point on the lane and then press enter. 
However, the next steps are not working:>> noise   = img((yn-2):(yn+2), (xn-2):(xn+2));
>> Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index 

>> means = (1:size(img,1)) * double(img(:,x)) ./ sum(double(img(:,x)), 1);
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
 
any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Sorry, if my comment is not legible--I am not sure how to add a new line to properly format.

Comment: your changes worked perfectly. Thankyou ! Can you please explain how you compute the mean (so that I can modify it to something else such as weighted mean) ? means = (1:size(img,1)) * double(img(:,round(x))) ./ sum(double(img(:,round(x))), 1);

Comment: Sure thing. As is, it is a weighted mean of all the pixels in the column you selected (for each lane). The weights are equal to `1 - image intensity` so that it gives you the mean of the *dark* region. In the code, the matrix multiplication operator `*` is used as a shortcut to do the weighted sums for all the lanes all at once (google "matrix multiplication" and you'll get a lot of nice demos). Then, for each lane, you just divide the weighted sum by the total weight to give you the final means. This is done with the array divide operator `./`.

Comment: if you click on this link http://goo.gl/ts3qw the equation L=... is the one that is suppose to be weighted mean; I am not sure how to modify your code to do that--perhaps in the first ginput a region (or a single thin rectangle along the center of the lane) needs to be selected to obtain the intensity (i.e. OD optical density) and then multiply by the y-axis which actually is in kilobases (actual linear length of the DNA) whose information does not exist in this lane. I am not sure if this is clear. I am pushing my luck but any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is what the code is already doing. `i` is one vertical pixel. `OD` is `1-lightness`, like we're doing. Averaging multiple pixels in the horizontal direction like you mention is another idea, but not mentioned in that link. For that you would do something similar to what I did for `noise`, where you could average the intensity over an x region about each of your clicks.

Comment: @LeeSande If this post solves your question, please consider up-voting it and accepting the answer (i.e. click the up arrow and check mark next to my post).

Comment: I would love to up-vote your comment but I have only 11 points but I need 15 points to up-vote. Soon I get that I will sure to do it. Your answer is perfect and super helpful! Thankyou for your generosity.

Comment: @LeeSande You can "accept" his answer as correct with the check mark, even if you cannot upvote.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to do to is convert your RGB image to grayscale:

```
gr = rgb2gray(imread('gelk.png'));
```

Then, take a look at the image intensity histogram using `imhist`.  Notice anything funny about it?  Use `imcontrast(imshow(gr))` to pull up the contrast adjustment tool.  I found that eliminating the weird stuff after the major intensity peak was beneficial.

The image processing task itself can be divided into several steps.

1. Separate each lane
2. Identify ('segment') the band in each lane
3. Calculate the location of the bands

**Step 1** can be done "by hand," if the lane widths are guaranteed.  If not, the line detection offered by the [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) is probably the way to go. The documentation on the Image Processing Toolbox has a really nice tutorial on this topic. My code recapitulates that tutorial with better parameters for your image. I only spent a few minutes with them, I'm sure you can improve the results by tuning the parameters further.

**Step 2** can be done in a few ways.  The easiest technique to use is Otsu's method for thresholding grayscale images.  This method works by determining a threshold that minimizes the **intra**-class variance, or, equivalently, maximizes the **inter**-class variance.  Otsu's method is present in MATLAB as the `graythresh` function.  If Otsu's method isn't working well you can try [multi-level Otsu](http://ivpl.eecs.northwestern.edu/research/projects/thresholding) or a number of other [histogram based threshold determination methods](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~ant/histthresh/).

**Step 3** can be done as you suggest, by calculating the mean y value of the segmented band pixels. This is what my code does, though I've restricted the check to just the center column of each lane, in case the separation was off. I'm worried that the result may not be as good as calculating the band centroid and using its location.

---

Here is my solution:

```
function [locations, lanesBW, lanes, cols] = segmentGel(gr)

%%# Detect lane boundaries
unsharp = fspecial('unsharp'); %# Sharpening filter
I = imfilter(gr,unsharp); %# Apply filter
bw = edge(I,'canny',[0.01 0.3],0.5); %# Canny edges with parameters
[H,T,R] = hough(bw); %# Hough transform of edges
P = houghpeaks(H,20,'threshold',ceil(0.5*max(H(:)))); %# Find peaks of Hough transform
lines = houghlines(bw,T,R,P,'FillGap',30,'MinLength',20); %# Use peaks to identify lines

%%# Plot detected lines above image, for quality control
max_len = 0;
imshow(I);
hold on;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   %# Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   %# Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
   len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
   if ( len > max_len)
      max_len = len;
   end
end
hold off;

%%# Use first endpoint of each line to separate lanes
cols = zeros(length(lines),1);
for k = 1:length(lines)
    cols(k) = lines(k).point1(1);
end
cols = sort(cols); %# The lines are in no particular order

lanes = cell(length(cols)-1,1);
for k = 2:length(cols)
    lanes{k-1} = im2double( gr(:,cols(k-1):cols(k)) ); %# im2double for compatibility with greythresh
end
otsu = cellfun(@graythresh,lanes); %# Calculate threshold for each lane
lanesBW = cell(size(lanes));
for k = 1:length(lanes)
    lanesBW{k} = lanes{k} < otsu(k); %# Apply thresholds
end    

%%# Use segmented bands to determine migration distance
locations = zeros(size(lanesBW));
for k = 1:length(lanesBW)
    width = size(lanesBW{k},2);    
    [y,~] = find(lanesBW{k}(:,round(width/2))); %# Only use center of lane
    locations(k) = mean(y);
end
```

I suggest you carefully examine not only each output value, but the results from each step of the function, before using it for actual research purposes.  In order to get really good results, you will have to read a bit about Hough transforms, Canny edge detection and Otsu's method, and then tune the parameters.  You may also have to alter how the lanes are split; this code assumes that there will be lines detected on either side of the image.

Comment: Many thanks for your help ! I will try it out and report back.

Comment: My code worked well on the original 'gelk' image, less so on the larger 'gele.' It's all in the Canny and Hough parameters.

Comment: I tried your code but the output is NaN and the image is displayed with green lines on the left and top. Although the code is written beautifully and commented very well, the image processing functions used are too complicated for me! Sincere thanks for your help.

Comment: This is why image processing is hard: it is very difficult to find parameters that work well for different images. If you eventually need a fully automated solution, at least you will have something to work with. @John Colby's answer is great if the interactivity is OK.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work well, by the way, is that the edges aren't detected well. If you come back to it, a Gabor filter will work very well in this case.

Comment: @reve_etrange: Nice job! I second the use of Otsu, but personally, I try to avoid having to find edges whenever possible.

Comment: @Jonas: lately I've been exploring Phase Congruency for that purpose and I'm favorably impressed so far. [Peter Kovesi](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/Research/MatlabFns/index.html) has a great set of functions to get started with it.  How to get the Hough parameters right seems most difficult to me, since it's hard to estimate them from the data and the results are very sensitive.

Comment: @reve_etrange: Thanks for the link. I'll try this out on my next image analysis challenge, though I really dislike code that doesn't allow you to easily estimate parameters based on the data.

Comment: @reve_etrange
that code exactly what i want also the discussion for the topic is very clear and simple
but the code doesn't work with me
if thier is any way to contact u please help

Comment: As Jonas implied above, the edge and line detection is the difficult part. Try different parameters for the edge detection and Hough transform / line detection steps (see MATLAB docs for more info). Parameter selection has a huge impact on results; those above are tuned for the original small "gelk" example image.  If you are also working on an electrophoresis gel, you might try Jonas' answer to this question, which uses some features of gel images quite ingeniously.

Answer (score 3):

Let me add another implementation similar in concept to that of [@JohnColby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8234137/97160)'s, only without the manual user-interaction:

```
%# read image
I = rgb2gray(imread('gele.png'));

%# middle position of each lane
%# (assuming lanes are somewhat evenly spread and of similar width)
x = linspace(1,size(I,2),10);
x = round( (x(1:end-1)+x(2:end))./2 );

%# compute the mean value across those columns
m = mean(I(:,x));

%# find the y-indices of the mean values
[~,idx] = min( bsxfun(@minus, double(I(:,x)), m) );

%# show the result
figure(1)
imshow(I, 'InitialMagnification',100, 'Border','tight')
hold on, plot(x, idx, ...
    'Color','r', 'LineStyle','none', 'Marker','.', 'MarkerSize',10)
```

[image: screenshot]

and applied on the smaller image:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Thanks for your input. Your answer looks great as well. This forum is super helpful!